# Multiple insert with add row

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i have form multiple insert. I am trying to insert items into the database and it's not working.
only 1 record can inserted. I don't know what's causing it

HTML :

```
<tbody id="itemlist">
        <tr>
            <td width="30%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNamabarang" name="txtNamabarang[0]" placeholder="Nama Barang" required></td>
            <td width="15%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtJumlahbarang" name="txtJumlahbarang[0]" placeholder="Jumlah"></td>
            <td width="15%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cmbSatuanbarang" name="cmbSatuanbarang[0]" placeholder="Satuan"></td>
            <td width="20%"><select id="cmbKategoribarang" class="form-control" name="cmbKategoribarang[0]" placeholder="Kategori">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value='Bahan Baku'>Bahan Baku</option>
                <option value='Barang Jadi'>Barang Jadi</option>
                <option value='Scrap'>Waste / Scrap</option>
                </select></td>
            <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtKet" name="txtKet[0]" placeholder="Keterangan"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="additem(); return false">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

I have SQL code like this :

```
$txtNamabarang =$_POST['txtNamabarang'];
            $txtJumlahbarang =$_POST['txtJumlahbarang'];
            $cmbSatuanbarang =$_POST['cmbSatuanbarang'];
            $cmbKategoribarang =$_POST['cmbKategoribarang'];
            $txtKet =$_POST['txtKet'];
            foreach ($txtNamabarang as $key => $n) {                
                $koneksidb->query("INSERT INTO tbl_pengeluaran_sementara_brg(nomor_pengeluaran_sementara_brg, nama_barang, jml_barang, sat_barang, kat_barang, ket) 
                                                VALUES('$kodeBaru', '$n', '$txtJumlahbarang[$key]', '$cmbSatuanbarang[$key]', '$cmbKategoribarang[$key]', '$txtKet[$key]')") or die ("Gagal Query Simpan barang".mysqli_error());
            }
```

my insert query not working, only 1 record can inserted

my Javascript like this :

```
var i = 1;
            function additem() {
//                menentukan target append
                var itemlist = document.getElementById('itemlist');
//                membuat element
                var row = document.createElement('tr');
                var namaBrg = document.createElement('td');
                var jumlahBrg = document.createElement('td');
                var satuanBrg = document.createElement('td');
                var kategoriBrg = document.createElement('td');
                var ketBrg = document.createElement('td');
                var aksi = document.createElement('td');
                aksi.setAttribute('align', 'center');
//                meng append element
                itemlist.appendChild(row);
                row.appendChild(namaBrg);
                row.appendChild(jumlahBrg);
                row.appendChild(satuanBrg);
                row.appendChild(kategoriBrg);
                row.appendChild(ketBrg);
                row.appendChild(aksi);
//                membuat element input
                var txtNamabarang = document.createElement('input');
                txtNamabarang.setAttribute('name', 'txtNamabarang[' + i + ']');
                txtNamabarang.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                txtNamabarang.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Nama Barang');
                var txtJumlahbarang = document.createElement('input');
                txtJumlahbarang.setAttribute('name', 'txtJumlahbarang[' + i + ']');
                txtJumlahbarang.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                txtJumlahbarang.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Jumlah');
                var cmbSatuanbarang = document.createElement('input');
                cmbSatuanbarang.setAttribute('name', 'cmbSatuanbarang[' + i + ']');
                cmbSatuanbarang.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                cmbSatuanbarang.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Satuan');
//                membuat element combobox
                var myParent = document.body;
                var array = ["Choose...","Bahan Baku","Barang Jadi","Scrap"];
                var cmbKategoribarang = document.createElement("select");
                cmbKategoribarang.setAttribute('name', 'cmbKategoribarang[' + i + ']');
                cmbKategoribarang.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                cmbKategoribarang.id = "mySelect";
                myParent.appendChild(cmbKategoribarang);
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = array[i];
                option.text = array[i];
                cmbKategoribarang.appendChild(option);
                cmbKategoribarang.appendChild(option);
                }
                var txtKet = document.createElement('input');
                txtKet.setAttribute('name', 'txtKet[' + i + ']');
                txtKet.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                txtKet.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Keterangan');

                var hapus = document.createElement('span');
//                meng append element input
                namaBrg.appendChild(txtNamabarang);
                jumlahBrg.appendChild(txtJumlahbarang);
                satuanBrg.appendChild(cmbSatuanbarang);
                kategoriBrg.appendChild(cmbKategoribarang);
                ketBrg.appendChild(txtKet);
                aksi.appendChild(hapus);
                hapus.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-small btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></i></button>';
//                membuat aksi delete element
                hapus.onclick = function () {
                    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
                };
                i++;
            }
```

i can't find the problem
Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi. SO tries to discourage wall of text type questions where a user asks people to look over the code and find the mistake. Try to find an aspect and ask for help with that. From looking, I can't tell where in the javascript you increment `i` so that there's some name advancement. In the PHP I can't see where you count up through each posted data. You may want to use `var_dump` on `$_POST` to see what data is coming through and start there.

Comment: your code is open to SQLinjections

Comment: Thank you for advice about my SQL

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is good. Edit the line containing txtket[]

```
<td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtKet" name="txtKet[]" placeholder="Keterangan"></td>
```

I hope with a vardump on your query, you'll be able to view the output.